# How to get the average of all the numbers from the list

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, runtime-error, user-input

I need to get the average test score from the numbers the user submitted and keep getting infinity. I need to know the average test score.
This is the student class:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int numOfQuizzes;
    private double totalScore;
    private ArrayList<Integer> scores;

    public Student(String name){
        this.name = name;
        scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;

    } public void addQuiz(int score){
        scores.add(score);
    }

    public double getTotalScore() {
        for(int score : scores){
            totalScore += score;
        }
        return totalScore;
    }

    public double getAverageScore(){
        return totalScore/(double)numOfQuizzes;
    }
}
```

This is what i have for the main:

```
    ArrayList<String> scores = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Request the name
    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    String name = inp.nextLine();

    // Create the student object
    Student student = new Student(name);

    // Ask for the grades
    System.out.print("Please enter your scores (q to quit): ");
    String grade = inp.nextLine();

    while (!grade.equals("q")) {
        // Convert the grade to an integer and pass it 
       **student.addQuiz(Integer.parseInt(grade));**
        //this is where the error is
        // Request a new grade
        grade = inp.nextLine();
    }

    // Report the results
    System.out.println("Students Name: " + student.getName());
    System.out.println("Total Quiz Scores: " + student.getTotalScore());
    double average = student.getTotalScore()/scores.size();
    System.out.println("Average Quiz Score: " + student.getAverageScore());
```

This is the Output:

```
What is your name? b
Please enter your scores (q to quit): 95
95
95
q
Students Name: b
Total Quiz Scores: 285.0
Infinity
Average Quiz Score: Infinity
```

As you can see I get infinity even when dividing the scores by the size.

Comment: What "runtime error"?

Comment: This `while (!grade.equals('q')) {` should never be true

Comment: did it only need to "q"? lol

Comment: I have no idea -- again, what is your error??

Comment: well, I added "q" instead and it took out the runtime error. but now the output is: Students Name: tom
Total Quiz Scores: 258.0
Average Quiz Score: Infinity(this should be the average)

Comment: or input string: "q"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at finalReview.FinalReview.main(FinalReview.java:73)

Comment: numOfQuizes is and remains 0, so you're always dividing by 0 when calc average.

Comment: so how can i have it keep track of the number of inputs to get the average?

Comment: Here's a thought question: why do you even need `numOfQuizzes`? You're adding to a list... A list has a size method

Comment: You should additionally check if said length is zero before you attempt to divide. For example, you entered q immediately should not produce an error

Comment: @cricket_007 this makes sense but I am trying to find an average grade. This means I need to get the score divided by the total score.

Comment: And you can. Using the existing total score method. Divided by the length of the list. **OR** Ask yourself: why are you not incrementing the number of scores as you add one?

Comment: At this point you should edit it to address the problem you're trying to solve in the comments. The post is still talking about the runtime error which you seem to have solved.

Comment: When using total score/size I still get infinity. and I don't know why.

Comment: @cricket_007 i have changed it.

Comment: Changed what? I still see that you have `numOfQuizzes` not being added to nor the list size method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make few changes in your code as shown below:

**Student Class:**

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private double totalScore;
    private ArrayList<Integer> scores;

    public Student(String name){
        this.name = name;
        scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;

    } public void addQuiz(int score){
        scores.add(score);
    }

    public double getTotalScore() {
        totalScore = 0;
        for(int score : scores){
            totalScore += score;
        }
        return totalScore;
    }

    public double getAverageScore(){
        return getTotalScore()/scores.size();
    }
}
```

**Main Class:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Request the name
        System.out.print("What is your name?: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();

        // Create the student object
        Student student = new Student(name);

        // Ask for the grades
        System.out.print("Please enter your scores (q to quit): ");
        String grade = input.nextLine();

        while (!grade.equals("q")) {
            // Convert the grade to an integer and pass it 
           student.addQuiz(Integer.parseInt(grade));
            // Request a new grade
            grade = input.nextLine();
        }

        // Report the results
        System.out.println("Students Name: " + student.getName());
        System.out.println("Total Quiz Scores: " + student.getTotalScore());
        System.out.println("Average Quiz Score: " + student.getAverageScore());
    }

}
```

Try to use this code, It will work correctly and display average score instead of `Infinity`.

**Changes Done:**

1. Removed `private int numOfQuizzes;` from **Student class**.
2. Added `totalScore = 0;` in `getTotalScore()` method in **Student class**.
3. Added `return getTotalScore()/scores.size();` in `getAverageScore()` method in **Student class**. Here `getTotalScore()` with return total score and `scores.size()` will return total number of scores. (3 in case of your example)
4. Removed `ArrayList<String> scores = new ArrayList<String>();` from **Main class**. As It is not needed in Main class.
5. Removed  `double average = student.getTotalScore()/scores.size();` because `student.getAverageScore()` in next line will calculate and return average value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've confused yourself holding onto two lists.

Remove the scores list in the main method. Also remove `totalScore` from the Student class; that is what is called a "calculated field"

Update the method

```
public double getTotalScore() {
   double totalScore = 0;
    for(int score : scores){
        totalScore += score;
    }
    return totalScore;
}
```

Then you'll actually want a loop like this to more accurately handle ordering of input validation

```
String grade;
do {
    grade = inp.nextLine();
    if (grade.equals("q")) break;
    // Convert the grade to an integer and pass it 
    student.addQuiz(Integer.parseInt(grade));
} while (true);
```

Then, remove `numOfQuizzes` from the Student class.

In the average method, that's where you use

```
return getTotalScore()/scores.size();
```

You're currently getting Infinity twice because

1. The main method scores are never added to
2. You're never incrementing `this.numOfQuizzes` in the Student class

Comment: where are you adding do { grade = inp.nextLine();?

Comment: In place of the current while loop. It's called a do-while

Comment: I have removed numofquizzes from my class file but I still am getting infinity using this

Comment: I suggest you print out the numbers as you add them, and walk through your code with a debugger. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I'm not sure what you've changed based on what I said. I'm not currently running this code to check it myself